# Bread-crumb style navigation for Winforms

Tags: winforms, navigation, breadcrumbs

Does anybody know of a bread-crumb style navigation for Winforms like the one from DotNetBar.

http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/BreadCrumbHorizontalTreeControl.aspx

I really like that control. However I am using a other UI library already and just for this control I do not want a reference to another 4 MB lib. I just need this control. Does anybody if something like this is available as a standalone control?

Answer (score 2):

I have used the Bread Crumb control of [Krypton Toolkit](http://www.componentfactory.com/), but you mentioned, that you don´t want an other UI library.

But maybe this source can help you, to build your own Bread Crumb control [Creating A Breadcrumb Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163764.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Try this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/BreadcrumbMenu.aspx) i haven't used it but (i use the one from Krypton) but i guess it will be good for you.
The one Jehof gave you is way better.

However take a look at Krypton suite, i always use it with the DevExpress XtraEditors. together you can create some great looking apps. i know you said that you don't want a huge library, but it's worth it.