# Is there a Windows 7 Folder location control or is custom code required?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I'm looking for a way to implement a Windows 7 folder location control in my app,  does anyone know a control that I could use to do this or some code to start me off?

For example:

[image: Something like this]

Comment: Just FYI, it's called the "breadcrumb bar"

Comment: There isn't anything like it built-in to .NET (either WinForms or WPF/Silverlight) but IIS Manager has a similar control, it works in both XP and Windows Vista/7, so you could try looking at it in Reflector and taking it from there.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure exactly what it was called so I'll see what google brings up.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239573/bread-crumb-style-navigation-for-winforms

Answer (score 0):

seems devcomponents has a good control that looks like it'll do the job so going to use that:

http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/BreadCrumbHorizontalTreeControl.aspx